# how to fill date picker with dates come from Database?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]

I have some specific dates stored in the database and I want to fill date picker with these dates values.
Is there a way to fill date picker from the database.

```
datePicker.fill(DbContext.FromDate);
```

Comment: Yes, but you need more details, what have you tried?  Is it a calendar date picker?  Or a drop down?  What code do you have for the date picker already?

Comment: Yep. Read from the database, and then assign the date values returned to the date picker. Vague questions call for vague answers ;)

Comment: calendar date picker fill it with dates for example from 01/01/2020 to 01/12/2020 only
not take all default dates

Comment: You'll want to [edit] your question to include which date picker component you are currently using (it appears to be the jQuery UI DatePicker, but I could be wrong). You may want to demonstrate that you've read the documentation for that component to see if it provides the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Break your problem into steps. 1) Read from database 2) Transfer that data to the client (optional if there is a server side tier) 3) Client displays that data in some UI control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope these link would help you:-

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-default-date-from-database

https://forums.asp.net/t/1822413.aspx?jquery+datepicker+fill+with+sql+database+dates

if you found these helpful please like it.. :-)